# Color of NavBar is different from background color

Tags: ios, swift, colors, sos

I have view which has background color like this:

`self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)`

And i have navBar which has color like:

```
nav1.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
```

They has different colors, how to solve this problem?

Comment: set nav1.navigationBar.translucent = false

Comment: it must be false instead of true @OlegGordiichuk

Comment: @NitinGohel thx small mistake

Comment: they are already not same. NavBar has white color ;\

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me, now its works)

Answer (score 0):

please use this to change the navigation bar background color

```
if floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 
{
     // iOS 6.1 or earlier
     self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
}
else 
{
     // iOS 7.0 or later
     self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 15/255, green: 52/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the story board than go to attribute  inspector 
the is a column extension edges   uncheck the option under the top bar. your color wold look different.

Answer (score -1):

Try `nav1.navigationBar.alpha = 1`